# upload django site to the web hosting service

Tags: django, web-services, web, django-webtest

Hello im about the finish my first ever `django` website and I dont know how to upload it to the internet Bcuz I want to buy a web hosting service and to run `django` server I need to run a command `python manage.py runserver` and how is the web hosting service gonna do it? how should I upload my `django` website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not easy to host a django project on a shared host. At least it come with a lot of problems that you have to face.

And you will need to use hostings that support a django project (Not only python). Django comes with requirements that not many hostings provide therefore i highly recommend to go with a VPS (Ubuntu for example) and host it yourself.

There is a lot of great docs for hosting a django project on a VPS and a lot of cloud services provide services for django.

Example:
[How To Serve Django Applications with uWSGI and Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score -1):

if you are fresher you need to create your on hosting service in your computer,
that is best idea for beginner,